C# struct with out parameter
This is probably very simple stupid question but I just need some help understanding it.  I'm storing a struct in a dictionary and I want to grab the struct change some values and then have it update automatically in the dictionary but the behavior is weird.
public struct Test
{
    public int a;
}

public class Tester
{
    public static Dictionary<int, Test> d = new Dictionary<int, Test>();

    public static bool GetTest(int position, out Test test)
    {
        if (d.ContainsKey(position)) {
            test = d[position];
            return true;
        } else {
            test = new Test();
            return false;
        }
    }
}


When I try grabbing a struct from the dict and change values it doesn't update.

        Test n = new Test();
        n.a = 10;
        Tester.d.Add(n.a, n);

        Tester.GetTest(10, out Test t1);
        Debug.Log(t1.a);

        t1.a = 20;

        Tester.GetTest(10, out Test t2);
        Debug.Log(t2.a);

Keeps showing 10.  So when I use the out parameter it makes a copy of the struct in the dict and returns that?  So I need to write an additional line to update the dictionary again right?
What would be a easy way of grabbing a struct and just updating its value in the dictionary without adding additional lines?
EDIT:
I could do this...
Tester.d[position].a = 20;

But is there a way to do that with a method?  Where I can get the whole struct, edit a value, and it updates in the dictionary automatically?  Sorry for the stupid question, i just dont understand the behaviour.

Why are you using a struct in the first place if you don't want the semantics of a struct?

" Where I can get the whole struct, edit a value, and it updates in the dictionary automatically?" by using a class maybe?? A struct has value-semantics, a class has reference-semantics.

You should not do that. While it is possible to change the value inside of a struct, even if the value is nested in a dictionary (such as in your example), you should try to avoid that and consider structs read-only. If you want to update a value of a dictionary, replace the entire value with a new instance instead of manipulating its contents. Chances are big the behavior is otherwise not what you'd expect.
The performance impact of doing a replacement should be minimal, too. So you can do
Tester.d[position] = new Test() { a = 20 };


Thanks for reply.

structs are not inherently read only. It is an implementation detail that we can't change the value in a dictionary (save for messing with the internal data structure as Theodor's answer)

@IvanPetrov I did not say that they're inherently read-only, but that it's best to use them that way. In fact, most (if not all) structs defined in the BCL are read-only.


I could do this...
Tester.d[position].a = 20;

You couldn't, unless d was an array.
Dictionary (like a List) does not have a ref-returning indexer, so you will always have a copy of the struct returned by the indexer and not the actual struct that is stored in the dictionary. As such your modifications won't be reflected back.
Short example:
var arr = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };
var list = new List<int> { 3, 4, 5 };
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int> { { 3, 4 }};

ref var arrVar = ref arr[0]; // array is ref returning indexer
arrVar = 5;

// list and dictionary are NOT
//ref var dictVar = ref dict[3];
//ref var listVar = ref list[0]; // non ref returning indexer
//listVar = 5;


Thanks for reply.

You could take a look at the ref return statement (support started on C# 7.0), as well as the APIs below:

CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef (.NET 6)
CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault (.NET 6)
Unsafe.IsNullRef (.NET 5)
Unsafe.NullRef (.NET 5)

You could use them like this:
public static ref Test GetTest(int position, out bool exists)
{
    ref Test test = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef(d, position);
    if (!Unsafe.IsNullRef(ref test))
    {
        exists = true;
        return ref test;
    }
    else
    {
        exists = false;
        return ref Unsafe.NullRef<Test>();
    }
}

Notice that I switched the position of the bool and Test return values. The ref magic works only with the return value, not with the out parameter.
Usage:
Test t = new Test();
t.A = 10;
d.Add(10, t);

ref Test t1 = ref GetTest(10, out _);
Console.WriteLine(t1.A);

t1.A = 20;

ref Test t2 = ref GetTest(10, out _);
Console.WriteLine(t2.A);

Output:
10
20

Online demo.

I'd also add the caveat of why this is unsafe (i.e. the underlying array that holds the struct being discarded for a new one)

@IvanPetrov yep, you are right. The documentation states explicitly that "​Items should not be added or removed from the Dictionary<TKey,TValue> while the ref TValue is in use."
